# match.arg() does not see an object declared in the other file (package development)

Tags: r, package

Given is a package with two files. In the first file I declare a variable (possible values), in the second I declare a function, which uses this variable as possible values for its argument.

```
# file1.R
pdfs <- c("norm", "t")
```

And the second file:

```
# file2.R 
f <- function(pdf = pdfs) {
    pdf <- match.arg(pdf)
    print(pdf)
}
```

The function sees the pdfs object (I tried to print it, and it works fine), but match.arg() does not work as expected, and throws the following error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  object 'pdfs' not found
```

At the same time this example below works, so I guess it is very likely an issue with environments.

```
a <- c("a", "b")
f <- function(x = a) {
    x <- match.arg(x)
    print(x)
}
f()
```

Session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.7.5 (Lion)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] s4chart_0.1.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] colorspace_1.2-6 scales_0.3.0     plyr_1.8.3       tools_3.2.1     
 [5] withr_1.0.2      gtable_0.1.2     Rcpp_0.12.1      memoise_1.0.0   
 [9] ggplot2_2.1.0    grid_3.2.1       digest_0.6.8     munsell_0.4.2   
[13] devtools_1.12.0
```

Comment: I found that the line in match.arg() that produces the error: `choices <- eval(formal.args[[deparse(substitute(arg))]])`

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to declare the argument this way instead of doing something like `f <- function(pdf = c("norm", "t"){ }`?since

Comment: Yes, 'cause I want to use the same possible values for several functions in several files.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a collation issue. Place `file1.R` above `file2.R` in the `Collate` field in the `DESCRIPTION` file. You can do that by using `#' @include file1.R` inside `file2.R` if you are using roxygen.